# Text-shadow issues with ie

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I am using following css rules to add some text-shadow.

```
.aaactive {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #990000;
}
```

I 've searched quite the web to find a solution for ie version < 10 (unfortunately many people use ie8-9 still) and found that i have to add one of the following filter rules  but unfortunately nothing seems to happen.

```
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(OffX=1, OffY=1, Color=990000);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(direction=135,strength=2,color=990000);
```

Is there a better solution or sth i am missing here?

Comment: Please show us your HTML, as well as the filter rules inside the CSS.  Give us a demo we can look at.

Comment: It is used here [link](http://www.franksdonuts.gr/mainpage/) for the top main menu items.